# MySQL multiple left join group by

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum, left-join

There is something wrong with this MySQL code.
it seems to be returning more stock then there should be.

table positions holds the stock available (multiple positions one product)
table orderbody holds the orders ordered products (1 orderheader  to many orderbody)

```
SELECT PRO.ProductID, 
       PRO.ProductCode, 
       SUM( POS.Qty ) AS instock, 
       SUM( OB.Qty ) AS onorder
FROM products AS PRO
LEFT JOIN position AS POS ON POS.ProductID = PRO.ProductID
LEFT JOIN orderbody AS OB ON OB.ProductID = PRO.ProductID
WHERE POS.ProductID = OB.ProductID
GROUP BY PRO.ProductID, POS.ProductID, OB.ProductID
```

- i'm getting instock 320
- actual stock quantity = 40
- number of positions = 2 (qty 20 each)
- onorder = 16 qty
- actual number of orderbody = 8 rows
- actually on order = 8 (each with qty = 1)

this is on one of the products

i know it has something to do with the group by but i cant work it out.

Appreciate any help received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. Try it by SELECTing from a separate query: SELECT ... FROM products, (SELECT...)..." where you have the two tables to be left joined. try to test the sub-query by itself first, and try to put it together once ot works. (once you have the data you want, and not duplicates, because that is you problem.

Comment: yes running them like the following works. But i thought there was a way to get this working like i had done it. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting this field PRO.ProductCode, but not grouping by it, at a guess it might be the problem.

Comment: no tried that it didnt help. what should be the result is one row for every product ID showing its ID, its code , whats currently in stock and whats currently on order.

productcode isnt being used in any way other then to just appear on the table. each productid also has its own productcode (unique i know duplicate unnecisary unique columns but hell why not)

Comment: it is very hard to offer any more suggestions without seeing the database structure, and some sample data. try removing the group by and the sum columns and look at the raw data being selected to see if you have more copies of stuff then you expect